# IFS change not coming into effect

Tags: bash

I was trying to change the `IFS`([Internal Field Separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)) character to comma for a file processing, but to my surprise the `IFS` was un-changed.

Here's the order of commands and output :

```
mtk4@mtk-laptop:~$ echo .$IFS.
. .                                    # A space
mtk4@mtk-laptop:~$ IFS=","             # No error was thrown, no message
mtk4@mtk-laptop:~$ echo .$IFS.
. .                                    # Again echo'd it, but no change
```

Please let me know, what is wrong here?

Comment: For future reference, `echo` is *not* a reliable way to inspect unknown variable values.  A much safer and more foolproof method would be something like `printf %s "$var" | od -t c` or your hex dumping tool of choice, to catch any unprintable ones.  The default value of `IFS` should be space, tab, newline.

Comment: Interestingly, zsh prints `IFS` properly with `echo`, but bash doesn't.

Comment: @Kevin That's because in zsh, variables's values do not undergo word splitting (this is zsh's most salient incompatibility with Bourne/POSIX shells). You'll see the same effect under `emulate sh` or with `echo .$=IFS.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IFS is also used as a separator when expanding a `$variable` with no quotes around it. In other words, you did change it, but, it got treated as a separator between the two dots. And, the `echo` command doesn't know what your $IFS is, and even if it did, it doesn't put it between its arguments for output, so you got a space there. Try `echo ".$IFS."`

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` you can use the builtin `printf` command with the `%q` format specifier to inspect the value of the `IFS` variable (see `help printf`).

```
printf '%q\n' "$IFS"    # $' \t\n'

# alternative, as already suggested by jw013
printf '%s' "$IFS" | od -A n -t x1 | xargs     # 20 09 0a
```